# CakePHP + admin routes + .htaccess + production mode

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

The following site shows a (kinda hack-ish) way to protect an admin route with .htaccess:

http://snook.ca/archives/servers/password_protect_admin/

If I understand it correctly, it only works because CakePHP runs a check for the 'real' file presence before it processes its own URL logic. So, when you request yoursite.com/admin, it checks for the default document in the (real, since we've created it) /admin dir, and this check triggers the authentication.

My issue is: the 'hack' works OK if I set my debug level to '1' or higher. If I set it to Production Mode ('0'), I just get a cake-interpreted HTTP 401 (Access Denied) error.

So, my question is: is there any way to make this 'hack' work with the debug level set to zero?

Comment: Why do you want to protect your admin routes in this way?  Just to have another challenge/response before allowing access?  I think you might be over-engineering this one.

Comment: If you just set your admin routes, they remain open for public access, unless you set a Authentication component to protect them. Since I don't need real user management (just password protection), I chose to use built-in Apache powered auth instead of the cake-powered one. So, I guess I'm actually under-engineering it. =D

Comment: even if you could get it to work, you should use auth component for maintainability and flexibility. besides, it's really easy to set it up

Comment: @FunkyDude: I understand, but it's a really small site, maintainability and flexibility being not an issue. Say, I would spend 2-3 hours configuring the auth component, and 10 minutes setting up the .htaccess. Also, it works already, I just wanna be able to use it in production mode. =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [SecurityComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/view/473/Basic-HTTP-Authentication) which lets you set up basic HTTP Authentication with a few lines of code in your `beforeFilter`. Should be a lot more robust than this hack.

---

I do agree though that the AuthComponent is terrifically easy to [set up](http://book.cakephp.org/view/172/Authentication). You just copy and paste the snippets for the UserController and login form, run the table creation script, try to log in, take the encoded password from the SQL log, put it in the database and add `Auth` to the component list in your controller. Takes less than 3 minutes and makes a better impression to the client (in case anybody cares ;)).

Comment: You people might be right, I am probably over-resisting using the Auth component lol. In any case, this SecurityComponent also looks interesting to me, I think I'll give it a shot. If it turns out over-complicated or under-featured, I guess I'll just stop complaining and try the Auth component. =D